# Access index.html in folder without 301 redirect

Tags: nginx, seo, http-status-code-301

I have some index.html files sitting in a folder to get some nice urls -

```
site.com/about
```

where index.html sits in the about folder.  But I am seeing that my site.com/about is being 301 redirected to `site.com/about/`  I am not sure where the 301 is generated from.  It is not in config.

/about/ also has a 301 result.

I guess it makes sense since I am redirecting to the index.html file but should it not be a rewrite?  Is there a way to return 200 for /about instead of 301 to about/?

I am using nginx

Server Block:

```
server {
    listen IP;
    server_name site.com;
    rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent;    

}

server {
    listen IP:80;
    server_name site.com *.site.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/site.com/htdocs;
    charset utf-8;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.php;
        expires 30d;
    }

    if ($request_uri = /index.php) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host;
    }   
    if ($request_uri = /index) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host;
    } 

    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }    
    include "ssl_offloading.inc";
    location ~ .php$ {
#        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /404.php last; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your server block. The fix is simple, but I would rather give specific advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [the site for Professional Wemasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: this is a config programming question not an SEO question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` directive and the `$uri/` element of the `try_files` directive, has the side-effect of adding a trailing `/` to directory names by performing an external redirect.

To avoid the external redirect and return an appropriate index file when presented with a slash-less directory name, implement the `index` functionality explicitly within the `try_files` directive:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.php;
    expires 30d;
}
```

Notice that `.php` works only in the last element at this location. If you need to check for `$uri/index.php` (in addition to `$uri.php`) you can use a named location block - and move or copy your *fastcgi configuration* into it.

For example (based on your server block):

```
root /var/www/vhosts/site.com/htdocs;

error_page 404 /404.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @php;
    expires 30d;
}
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;

    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    ...
    fastcgi_pass ...;
}

location = /index.php { return 301 $scheme://$host; }
location = /index { return 301 $scheme://$host; }
location /. { return 404; }

location ~* \.php(/|$) { rewrite ^(.*)\.php $1 last; }

include "ssl_offloading.inc";
```